# Load balance Kafka record consumption when using topic pattern

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If two processes which uses the same consumer group (group.id) subscribe to the same *topicPattern* - will Kafka than load balance the resolved topics between the two processes?

In my case about 400 topics match the pattern and each topic has one partion. I wonder if I can load balance the consumption of the topics via different processes with the same consumer group but it seems that only one process handles all the topics. Is this because only partitions are load balanced - or maybe because a topic *pattern* is used by the subscription?

---

I made some deeper debugging. My test setup is not really two processes but two threads - I guess that should not matter. Debug printing the topic description outputs something like this (IPs are obfuscated):

```
(groupId=foo-bar-group, isSimpleConsumerGroup=false, 
  members=
   (memberId=KafkaTestApplication:KafkaTestApplication-1-20126d55-678d-46f5-bc73-3769db2c8901, 
     clientId=KafkaTestApplication:KafkaTestApplication-1, 
     host=/aa.bb.c.dd, 
     assignment=(topicPartitions= <all topics here>)),
   (memberId=KafkaTestApplication:KafkaTestApplication-2-8d34e81a-8f57-4d4e-bd9e-b56edc4e706c, 
     clientId=KafkaTestApplication:KafkaTestApplication-2,
     host=/aa.bb.c.dd, 
     assignment=(topicPartitions=)), 
     partitionAssignor=range, 
     state=Stable, 
     coordinator=aaa.bb.ccc.d:9092 (id: 9 rack: null)
)
```

I can see that I have two different members in the consumer group with two different clientIds. Nevertheless all topics are assigned to the first consumer and the second consumer has no topics assigned. I expected that both members get some topics. Both members poll every few seconds.

Comment: How are you checking "it seems" this way? And do you really want 200 partitions per consumer process? Seems like a lot

Comment: For now I only checked by inspecting the logs :-| - In case rebalancing works I would probably start as much processes as needed to handle the expected amount of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what to change to get the desired topic/partition balancing. I had to set the Consumer property

```
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

The default settig (`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor`) does not work for my setup. Why is explained [here](https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab) as user152468 mentioned in the comments. Thanks for that!

Comment: Good catch. This is explained quite well on this blog post: https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab

Answer (score 1):

When the second process of the same group starts, the group should rebalance the Topic *partition* assignment, yes.

However, I've not had any experience with subscription patterns, but I don't expect it to work differently than providing a direct list of topics

Comment: So does it mean (or do you expect) that even topics with only one partion will be moved to the second process?

Comment: They should be, yes. If you describe the consumer group, you should be able to at least see two IPs or client ids (assuming these are in fact different)

Comment: [JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.regex.Pattern-) also says that rebalancing should take place. So I guess there is a fault on my side. Will work a while on this topic an come back later. Thanks for the moment.

Comment: Does not work as I expect. Added the consumer group description output to the question. All topics are assigned to the first member. I have no idea why :-(.

Comment: What client language are you using? Are you actually able to run two *processes*? And the IP is the same becuase it's two threads on one machine?

Comment: I am using the Java Consumer API and yes, 1 process with 2 Threads (Consumer) on the same machine. I can probably run the program twice and will try this tomorrow.